# Excel non-volatile fill dynamic range

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, array-formulas

In Excel: I have a data column `A`, and I want to populate a column `C` with a subset of `A`.  The user will frequently change the values in cells indicating the `StartRow` and `EndRow` of `A` to put in `C`.

This can be done with the following array formula `{=INDEX(A:A,StartRow):INDEX(A:A,EndRow)}` ... except that the formula has to be filled down to the maximum number of rows that could ever be specified.  For all rows past (`EndRow`-`StartRow`) the formula will return #N/A.  Of course those can be turned into empty values using further logic, but all of this logic will complicate formulas and take precious CPU cycles.  (This is the simplest case; obviously more complicated formulas and references will populate the target column.)

Is there any way to dynamically fill a formula down an exact number of rows, so that the last row of the fill range is always (`EndRow`-`StartRow`)?  And to do so without using volatile functions?

Comment: Perhaps Table can do the trick, something like `{=INDEX(Table1[Column1],1):INDEX(Table1[Column1],ROWS(Table1)}`
However users will need to be educated on using Tables

Comment: If you could be more specific about it, e.g. the user will add data in column A, then in column 'B' the unique values of column 'A' will be updated if the input was unique. A 'CountIf' formula in column 'C' will calculate the number of occurrences of the values from column 'B' in column 'A'...etc.An interesting example that comes to mind could be if the user is only changing (adding) values in column 'A', a VBA solution with the Change_event can be written without the need of a single formula on the worksheet. Everything could get calculated after the user e.g. presses enter.

Comment: In EXCEL 365 for example there are [dynamic array formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531) which spill over as needed.

Comment: @OverflowStacker I was thinking there should be something like that, but when I enter `{=INDEX(A:A,StartRow):INDEX(A:A,EndRow)}` with CSE it does not spill down; I only get one cell back if I only have one cell selected.  I can't find a dynamic array formula equivalent.